# "Failed to execute default File Manager: Input/output error"

Tags: nautilus, filemanager

I am getting the below error when I try to go Places > Home Folder for example. I can run `nautilus` manually though.

[image: Failed to execute default File Manager dialog]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a problem caused by setting the "open with" command for folders to "terminal"

Fix from command line:

`mimeopen -d ~/Desktop/`

You will get this:

```
Please choose a default application for files of type inode/directory

    1) Open Folder  (nautilus-folder-handler)
    2) Other...

use application #
```

Choose Nautilus and you fixed the problem!

Comment: This appears to be a 1 time fix only? The next time I try opening the folder, I get the same problem?

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar problem, although I believe mine was caused by associating an application with a filetype in Firefox.  Running the `mimeopen -d ~/Desktop/` command didn't work, but this command did:

```
exo-preferred-applications -c
```

In the window that appears, change your default file manager back to your usual choice.

Comment: thanks this is really work.really thanks you can't understand how it's help me.

Comment: Not even this worked for me... So I was forced to install PCManFM and `sudo apt purge nautilus`, bookmarks remained :)

Answer (score 0):

Go to Ubuntu Software Center and uninstall any extra file managers you may have (leave Nautilus as your sole file manager).

This was the only thing that fixed the problem for me.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

This is for those like me who are encountering this scenario  after upgrading to the recent Debian 10 (Buster) as of late 2019 - early 2020.

I used two techniques in attempt to determine the failures:

1. Use `dmesg`: For example, execute `sudo dmesg | tail` right after the failure incident to determine the logs indicating failure.
2. Run the file manager from within a terminal to see `stderr` output of the app when the failure incident happens.

Steps of resolution that worked for me:

1. Customization of date format having options such as `%V` or `%T` is not appreciated. Case in point is Thunar (as of version 1.8.4). These need to be removed or replaced by more traditional formats.
    *Example*: replace `%T` with `%H:%M:%S`.
2. Installation of file tools that integrate with file managers (example: [Beyond Compare](https://scootersoftware.com)) employs extensions that are not compatible with file managers yet. The extensions need to be removed/disabled.
    *Example*: check which extensions are causing failure by observing `stderr` and remove the offending extension from `/usr/lib/<your architecture>-<your kernel name>/thunarx-3`.